# Informatica no spaghetti exercise

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a source qualifier with 4 ports in this exact order: A, B, C, D.
I have to process the data so that using only one expression and NO spaghetti links I get to a target with the same ports but in the following order: A, D, B, C.
How could I do that?

Comment: I am unclear on your requirement - do you want to keep target column order `ABCD` ? Or you want data to be ordered too ? If yes to first question and no to second then - Informatica never alters order of port, so you should get same order as you connect to a file or to a DB target. If your answer is yes to both then you need to use sorter to order data.

Comment: I do not want to order the data, I simply want to change the order of the ports in target.

Comment: if target is flat file - just modify informatica target definition. if target is table - then you need to change Database definition of the target and modify the column order there(you dont have to make any change in informatica).

Answer (score 0):

This requirement is... dumb. Yet, if you still need to achieve it, just create an expression with the following port definitions:

```
in_A
in_B
in_C
in_D
out_A = in_A
out_D = in_D
out_B = in_B
out_C = in_C
```

Now, all your links will be parallel, no crossings.

PS.
Please tell the recruiter to come up with something that actually makes sense...